# What does this command mean: awk -F: '{print $4}'?

Tags: command-line, awk

Please explain what does following command mean:

```
awk -F: '{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
awk -F: '{print $4}'
```

- `awk` - this is the interpreter for the AWK Programming Language. The AWK language is useful for manipulation of data files,
     text retrieval and processing
- `-F <value>` - tells `awk` what field separator to use. In your case, `-F:` means that the separator is `:` (colon).
- `'{print $4}'` means  print the fourth field (the fields being separated by `:`).

#### Example:

Let's say that there's a file called `test`, and it contains the following:

```
Hello:my:name:is:Alaa
```

If we execute the command `awk -F: '{print $4}' test`, the output will be:

```
is
```

Because `is` is the fourth field.

```
      field1   field3  field5
       -----    ----    ----
       |   |    |  |    |  |
       Hello:my:name:is:Alaa
             ||      ||
             --      --
           field2  field4
```

Answer (score 9):

- You set the field separator with ...

  ```
  -F
  ```

  so that is ":" in this example.
- You print the text that is between the 3th and 4th separator with ...

  ```
  '{print $4}'
  ```
- And this explains it better:

  ```
  echo "154:266:377:454:533" | awk -F: '{print $4}'
  454
  ```

Comment: what if i want to print `454 154:266:377:454:533` print $4 and the entire line together separated by space?